# unable to free pointer after constructing a vector c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I need to populate a vector variable from a char** variable that i get from another function.

I tried on my own the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
char** getS();
int main()
{
    int i;
    vector<string> a;
    cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    char** b=getS(); 
    char c[][5] = {"one","two","thr"};


    //a.insert(a.begin(), b, b+3);

    for(i=0;i<3; i++)
    {
        a.push_back(b[i]);
    }


    for(i=0;i<3; i++) 
        free(b[i] );

    free(b); 

    for(i=0;i<3; i++)
    {
        cout <<a[i].c_str() << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}

char** getS()
{
    char** list; 
    int number_of_row=3,number_of_col =5,i;
    list = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*number_of_row);
    for(i=0;i<number_of_row; i++) 
    {
        list[i] =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*number_of_col);  
        list[i] ="Hello";
    }

    return list;
}
```

I tried executing it in the [this site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php).

I am getting an invalid pointer error and a dump in console.
But I believed pointers can be freed as i did above after pushing the values into a vector.
If i remove the freeing of pointer b then the code works fine.

I need to use this vector after freeing the original char** variable from which it was populated.

length of the string array in char** is hardcoded in my example.

Comment: You have a vector of string yet you malloc char*, why!?!

Comment: Looks like you are trashing your memory with `list[i] ="Hello";`.  `"Hello"` actually requires 6 characters and you only sized the array for 5.

Comment: Who ever teaches you to write C++ like this, hit him in the head with a [real book.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (Or at least get one for yourself, using `malloc` like this is a baaad idea for example.)

Comment: the main aim of this sample code is to test whether freeing up of pointers, after converting a char** into a vector<string>, works fine. Thanks for pointing out other issues with the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
list[i] ="Hello";
```

This doesn't copy the string into the memory you have allocated, it overwrites *the pointer*. After that statement, you have lost the pointer you have allocated, and instead made it point to a string literal (which is allocated statically by the compiler, and should not be free'd by you). If you insist using character pointers you should use [`std::strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) to copy the string contents.

---

However, you are programming in C++, so why are you even bothering with pointers? You have [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), you have [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), use them all through your program and you will not have problems like this.

Comment: Exactly. You're not allowed to `free()` static strings and you get a segmentation fault if you try to. Secondly, I'd also like to point out that mixing C++ containers and `char**` is not a good idea unless you really know what you're doing (e.g. interoperability with C code), and you should use `std::string` whenever possible.

Comment: Use strdup to duplicate a string in C. Prefer std::string in C++.

Comment: @Joachim: can you please tel me whether the commented line a.insert(a.begin(), b, b+3); is better than the for loop for populating the vector?